# View hierachy not prepared for constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .ExtraLight)) as UIVisualEffectView
    self.view.insertSubview(self.blurView, belowSubview: self.filterPanel)

    self.blurView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.blurView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    self.blurView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.blurView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    self.blurView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.blurView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    self.blurView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.blurView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
}
```

When the above code is called it crashes with the error "The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint". I can understand this error being generated if I'm trying to add the constraint before it's been added to the view but the view is inserted which is then followed by the constraints being added.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

Constraints need to be added to a common ancestor of all involved views (where a view is considered an ancestor of itself for this purpose). `self.blurView` is a subview of `self.view`. The constraints involve both `self.blurView` and `self.view`. Therefore, the constraints need to be added to `self.view`, not `self.blurView`.

By the way, your clue should be this part of the error message (which you didn't quote, but your associated did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28527272/1312143)):

> When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself.
It turns out I should have done "addSubview" before executing "addConstraints".
Once the order was reversed, all the error messages were gone.